# Extracting values from .ovr pyramid files provides NA in R? getValues?

Tags: raster, r, extract

I'm trying to extract values from many rasters to specific points and have those values be in columns that are labeled as the raster name. I can do it all here except get the values. All projections match. Is this due to the fact that is an ovr type raster?

```
m <- "E:/./"
allFiles <- list.files(m, full.names = T,pattern = "_ex0315.ovr",
                       no.. = TRUE, recursive=TRUE)
filenamez <- str_split_fixed(allFiles, "/", 6)[,5]
allFiles <- stack(allFiles)

names(allFiles) <- filenamez
projection(allFiles) <- CRS("+proj=utm +zone=14 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0") 

Choruspts<-read.csv(".")

corproj<-CRS("+proj=utm +zone=14 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0")

points <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(Choruspts[,2:3], Choruspts,
                                 proj4string = corproj)   

points.mrc <- spTransform(points, CRS(projection(allFiles)))

output<-as.data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow(Choruspts), length(filenamez)))

dim(output)
for(i in 1:length(filenamez)) {
    output[, i] <- extract(allFiles[[i]], points, method="bilinear")
}
names(output) <- filenamez

fulloutput <- cbind(Choruspts, output)
```

The output has the 3 columns of the point files and column headers of the 399 rasters but the values are all NAs.

```
dim(output)
[1] 200 399
```

For example:

```
head(fulloutput)
  Location Easting Northing A1_2013-04-06_650 A1_2013-04-06_710 A1_2013-04-06_730 A1_2013-04-06_750 A1_2013-04-20_640
1 A1 E 100  427572  4676098                NA                NA                NA                NA                NA
2 A1 E 200  427672  4676098                NA                NA                NA                NA                NA
3 A1 E 400  427872  4676097                NA                NA                NA                NA                NA
4  A1 E 50  427522  4676099                NA                NA                NA                NA                NA
5 A1 E 800  428073  4676090                NA                NA                NA                NA                NA
6 A1 N 100  427465  4676203                NA                NA                NA                NA                NA
```

I have determined that the stack is lacking values, which should be the last entry on the bottom:

```
class       : RasterStack 
dimensions  : 1436, 801, 1150236, 399  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
extent      : 0, 801, 0, 1436  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=utm +zone=14 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0 
names       : A1_2013.04.06_650, A1_2013.04.06_710, A1_2013.04.06_730, A1_2013.04.06_750, A1_2013.04.20_640, A1_2013.04.20_700, A1_2013.04.20_740, A1_2013.04.20_800, A1_2013.04.20_820, A1_2013.04.20_840, A1_2013.04.20_900, A1_2013.04.20_920, A1_2013.04.27_617, A1_2013.04.27_644, A1_2013.04.27_708, ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The points you are using do not seem to overlap with the extent of your RasterStack

```
extent      : 0, 801, 0, 1436  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
```

The extent look suspect, it would be area of about 1 by 1 km (which is of course possible) with one edge on the equator.